# How to check if a user is in a particular group from a particular OU in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Here's my question.

I have multiple OUs that represent physical locations so it's structured like this.

COMPANY.COM\LOC1\Users (user1, user2, user3 etc...)
COMPANY.COM\LOC2\Users (user4, user5, user6 etc...)

Each location has a group that the user should be a part of and I need to audit to make sure users are a part of that group.

OU LOC1, I need to make sure all users (user1, user2, user3) in OU LOC1 are a part of security group LOC1_GRP and output the ones that aren't.

Comment: What have you tried so far? which kind of library/snapin you'd like to use?

Answer (score 2):

what about [Get-QADUser](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Get-QADUser)? You can filter all users for example not belonging to a specific group like this:

```
get-qaduser -searchroot 'company.com/LOC1/Users' | ? {[string]$_.memberof -notmatch 'LOC1_GRP'}
```

Comment: I believe .memberof is going to be an array of group DNs, which complicates things. I think {[string]$_.memberof -notmatch 'LOC1_GRP'} might work without having to interate through all the group DNs checking for a match.

Comment: @mjolinor: I think you are true. I've corrected the answer. Thanks

Comment: @mjolinor: sure we need `notmatch`, not sure it's an array.

Comment: I believe whether or not it will be an array will depend on whether the user is a member of multiple groups.  In my experience it is very rare that a use belong to only one security group.

Comment: @empo, do you really test it ? if a user is created in the OU without having been assign to any group, this will not work. just because memberof is empty in this case.

Comment: I don't understand why it would not work. If they don't belong to any group, .memberof will return $null.  $null -notmatch 'LOC1_GRP' will return $true, the expected result since they do not belong to that group.

Comment: memberof will just be absent, so in my case $_.memberof is not $null but absent. Perhaps different with Quest Cmdlet, so the question, do you test it ?

Comment: I'm not following.  memberof is an attribute of the returned object. It cannot be absent, but may be empty. [string]@() -notmatch 'LOC1_GRP' still returns $true.

Comment: Sorry guys, normally I'm not able to test powershell during the week-end. This was just a suggestion/direction to the OP. The question is a mess, and the OP didnt provide any useful detail, any code sample, and, moreover, he's not showing any interest to it. We shouldnt have given an answer at all. This question worth it?

Comment: @mjolinor when you work with AD attribute, they can be absent. I can access my AD and I TEST IT.

Comment: Whether the attribute is present in AD is a different question than whether the object returned by Get-QADUser will have that property.

Comment: In the example given, yes. Any use of where-object is a test, and in this example, that's what's being tested.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
$groupname = "cn=group-blarr,ou=loc1,dc=company,dc=com"

Get-ADUser -filter {memberof -ne $groupname} -ResultPageSize 0 -SearchBase "ou=loc1,dc=company,dc=com" -Searchscope 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete (and correct) the first answer :

1. Quest Cmdlet to query Active-Directory are usable since PowerShell V1.0, but in PowerShell V2.0 (W2K8 R2) Microsoft implement its own (just import ActiveDirectory module)
2. Be carefull with `memberOf` attribute in Active-Directory because it's just empty when you create a user even if the user is member of the domain user group (which is code in the primaryGrouID) so that is why I reverse the test.

---

```
PS C:\> get-adobject -SearchBase "ou=loc1,dc=company,dc=com"  -filter {objectclass -eq "user"} -properties memberof | where {!($_.memberof -match "mygroup")}
```